# Why is this resource throwing a "cannot be resolved or is not a field" error?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a file `/res/values/maps_api_key.xml` where I defined my Google Maps API key:

```
<resources>
    <string name="maps_api_key">03xx123124exapmle4444444c9yA</string>
</resources>
```

This is the line of my application code which throws an error:

```
mMapView = new MapView(this, getString(R.string.maps_api_key));
```

This is the error:

```
maps_api_key cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

I have imported resources as:

```
import android.R;
```

Why this marked by Eclipse as an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to `import android.R;`, but be sure to include a string:

```
package my.cool.package.name;
```

at beginning of your .java file (replace with your actual package name ofcourse)